# How to get all users id using shards?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How to get all users id using shards?
**Code:**`client.shard.fetchClientValues('users.cache.map(({ id }) => id)')`

Answer (score 0):

I that your code you tried out? I would guess:

```
client.shard.fetchClientValues('users.cache').then(results => results.map(({ id }) => id))
```

or

```
const results = await client.shard.fetchClientValues('users.cache');
const ids = results.map(({ id }) => id);
```

Altho I have never used discord.js, I have no clue what any of this does.